# MySQL Correlated Query Confusion

Tags: mysql

Jumping right in, here is the MySQL query that isn't working:

```
SELECT S.pub
FROM serves S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT L.beer
                    FROM likes L
                    WHERE L.drinker = "Joe" AND L.beer NOT IN ( SELECT S.beer
                                                                FROM S));
```

The intent of this query is to select pubs that serve all the beers that Joe likes. However, when I try to execute it, I get an error saying that table S does not exist (as caused by "SELECT S.beer FROM S"). But I aliased S to an instance of the serves table in the outer FROM clause. What am I doing wrong?

Also it seems overly complicated to me that I am using NOT EXISTS and NOT IN. Is there a more elegant way of structuring this query?

Here is the database schema by the way:

```
LIKES(drinker,beer);
FREQUENTS(drinker,pub);
SERVES(pub,beer,cost);
```

Also, this question is related to my homework, so please take that into account when answering the question. Thank you.

Comment: The order of Execution start from inner sub query. So the Serves S alias won't work in the inner subquery.

Comment: If that's the case that execution starts from the inner subquery, then how do correlated subqueries work in general? For example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Comment: Actually the Query which you used is non-correlated subquery which is dependent query. So for each row the inner query gets executed for an outer query

Comment: What actually is your question? If you want to know a correct way of achieving a specific result, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. If correlated subqueries are a requirement of the assignment, make that clearer too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use join

```
SELECT S.pub FROM  SERVES S INNER JOIN LIKES L ON L.drinker = "Joe" AND L.beer= S.beer;
```

I think this will helps your problem  OR

You can use this

```
SELECT S.pub
    FROM serves S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT L.beer
                        FROM likes L
                        WHERE L.drinker = "Joe" AND L.beer IN ( SELECT SS.beer
                                                                    FROM serves SS));
```

Comment: I think the query you suggested using INNER JOIN selects the pubs that serve at least one beer that Joe likes, but I need it to select the pubs that serve all the beers that Joe likes.

And the 2nd query you suggested using SS as an alias returns extra results. I need S and SS to be confined to the same Serves table but if you use different aliases, they can be different.

At least that's my understanding.

Comment: Check this link :- http://rextester.com/XWN70954. Let me know if anything i missed.

Comment: That's such a useful website. Anyway yeah, the query returned pub1 and pub3 (twice), but none of them should be returned. Joe likes beer1, beer2, and beer3. For a pub to be returned, it must serve beer1, beer2, and beer3. Pub1 only serves beer1 and pub3 only serves beer1 and beer3, so neither of them should be returned.